# Get the required header name from function name

Tags: linux-kernel

Let's say I want to know that slab.h is required to use kmalloc(). I search for kmalloc in the documentation and get this page https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/mm-api.html?highlight=kmalloc#.
So I know it's related to memory management and "the slab cache", but I see no mention of slab.h.

What's the correct way of determining what header needs to be included in your module program ?

Comment: Function `kmalloc` and related are part of the kernel itself. You need no additional "module" for being able to use it.

Comment: Compilation returns implicit declaration warnings.

Comment: So you need a **header** (which is used by a compiler), not a *module* (which is used by the linker or at your module's loading stage). You may search a file which defines given function (e.g. on [this site](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/ident)). Note, that it is just a plain search, so its results are not always are *preferrable* (e.g. it finds `linux/slab_def.h` for `kmalloc` while the proper way is to include `linux/slab.h`). As far as I know there is no list of **all functions** with corresponded header, as Linux kernel evolves rapidly.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to say (used to python vocabulary, my bad). Ok, I'm a bit disappointed, I think it should be mandatory for a project of this size to be able to know which header include without having to search through the entire Q&A internet websites. But I suppose I'll have to cope with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get to know one of the Linux kernel cross-reference sites (LXR), which can tell you where things are defined.

i.e.:
  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/kmalloc